# I am unsure about how to count how many times certain conditions are met

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, counting

I am building a program in Visual Studio that is a "Guess the Word" game.

What happens is, my array generates a Word, and an input box appears. The user has to guess that word by entering text into the input box, and if it is right a message box will show well done, and if not, a message box will appear saying try again.

I need a function that will count how many words the user guesses right. I have this, but if the word is equal to the users input, 1 will appear in the label I set it to appear in, and if it isn't equal to it, a 0 will appear. This code worked (with different variables etc.) when I was counting the amount of times a certain button was clicked, so I'm confused about why it's not working now.

```
Dim guess As String
guess = (LCase(InputBox("What is the word", "Guess the word")))      
Static hits As Integer
hits = 0
If word = guess Then hits += 1
Label8.Text = hits
```

where `word` is the word generated by my array.

Why is the above code not incrementing the number of correct guesses?

Comment: `hits = 0` appears to be run every time just after you show the input box. So it resets to 0 on each guess. Just declare that variable and set it 0 once when the user starts the game, and reset it to 0 only when they start a new game.

Comment: You are probably running this inside some button/element-event sub and you reset the hits variable every time. So it should be declared as global outside the sub.

Answer (score 1):

It goes wrong because you have

```
Static hits As Integer
hits = 0
```

which means that `hits` is set to 0 each time it executes the line `hits = 0`.

If instead you use

```
Static hits As Integer = 0
```

then it will initialise it to 0, and it will do that only once.

Comment: It's an exact answer of the original question and an expansion of your answer... However, let's give the OP another one!

Answer (score 0):

As the others suggested, initialize the `hits` variable at the point of declaration and get rid of the assignment line:

```
Static hits As Integer = 0 ' Modify the declaration like this line
' hits = 0 - remove this line
```

Another solution is to have the `hits` variable declared at a [module level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/declaration-contexts-and-default-access-levels), in which case the `Static` keyword is not necessary:

```
Private hits As Integer = 0
```

Then access it wherever you like in your code and rest assured that its value is preserved between calls to your methods.
In any case, you need to make sure, that this line is gone:

```
hits = 0
```